# Why do we have both vsx and vs-extensibility tags on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms, clean-up

I think [vsx](/questions/tagged/vsx) and [vs-extensibility](/questions/tagged/vs-extensibility) should be synonyms. Since [vs-extensibility](/questions/tagged/vs-extensibility) is more explicit, it can be the main tag.

Tag counts:

- [vsx](/questions/tagged/vsx): 242
- [vs-extensibility](/questions/tagged/vs-extensibility): 90
- [extensibility](/questions/tagged/extensibility):233 - many of these could be retagged if they are actually about [vs-extensibility](/questions/tagged/vs-extensibility)
- [visual-studio-extensions](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-extensions) 139 - this is not a synonym and has to do with finding, installing, and using extensions others have written - it needs a cleanup because it contains a lot of questions about writing and debugging extensions
- [visual-studio-addins](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-addins): 278 - this is an older style of extension. It should never appear with [vsix](/questions/tagged/vsix) - but it does. Sigh.
- [add-in](/questions/tagged/add-in): 1138 - many of these could be retagged if they are actually about [visual-studio-addins](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-addins)
- [vsix](/questions/tagged/vsix): 132 - this could be combined with either [vs-extensibility](/questions/tagged/vs-extensibility) if you're trying to make a vsix, or [visual-studio-extensions](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-extensions) if you're trying to use one, but it doesn't really add much to the question to have it exist
- [visual-studio-templates](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-templates): 39 - another form of extensibility, this tag could be used either for writing them or using them
- [itemtemplate](/questions/tagged/itemtemplate) - seems to be designed for UI item templates, both ASP.NET and WPF, but occasionally mixed with [visual-studio-templates](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-templates) since Visual Studio templates come in Project and Item flavours
- [project-template](/questions/tagged/project-template) - as above
- [wizard](/questions/tagged/wizard) - generally useless meta tag with 444 questions. Any that relate to VSX should lose the tag imo.
- [parameters](/questions/tagged/parameters) - enormously useless meta tag with over 4000 questions probably any one of which is dying to be edited and improved
- [vspackage](/questions/tagged/vspackage): 94
- [visual-studio-shell](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-shell): 10
- [visual-studio-sdk](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-sdk): 74
- [envdte](/questions/tagged/envdte): 152 - this is an important library/namespace when writing both addins and extensions

These need some skill to retag. People are tagging stuff as add-ins when it's for VS2012, and as VSX when it's for 2008, and so on.

My specific request is for the synonym, but if anyone is inspired to write a tag wiki and do some retagging, that would be great too. These questions are fragmented across the tags and I think people are missing questions and answers that would help them.

Comment: I don't know about the topic but isn't it conceivable that someone asks about a tool that they want to provide for both 2008 and 2012 and thus tag it as both [tag:vsix] *and* [tag:visual-studio-addins]?

Comment: They would almost certainly need to write two tools. And deciding to support VS2008 now, when both 2010 and 2012 versions are out there, is a very low return activity. In any case, they would certainly need to ask two questions.